# Android, final class Void

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have noticed AsyncTask method doInBackground() returns an object with class type Void instead of simple void

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Cursor... params) {
    return null;
}
```

What is that used for? Especially if that class can not be instantiated.

Comment: From [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) `Not all types are always used by an asynchronous task. To mark a type as unused, simply use the type Void`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `AsyncTask` has to have *some* return type `T` to satisfy the interface contract, but some tasks don't have a value to return (e.g., maybe just "done" or an exception for failure). In this case, the `doInBackground` can't be `void`, but it can be something else--in this case, `Void`, which is specifically intended for situations where a generic return type is specified but the implementation has nothing to return.